# D3 prevent appending duplicates

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, duplicates

I have the following function to draw different SVG shapes with D3.

```
updateChart(props){
var svg = d3.select(this.refs.svg);
let prefix = "XX";
 // Render SVG Tags with ID and without attributes first
  let objectsRender = svg.selectAll("line")
                       .data(props.data)
                       .enter()
                       .append(function(d) {
                            return document.createElementNS(
                            "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
                             d.objType);
                         })
                       .attr("id", function(d){ return prefix +d._id;})
                       .attr("class", "no-attr")
                       .on("click",(d)=>{this.modeClick(d);});

 // Set Attributes for all classes with no attributes set so far

 let objectsAttributes=  svg.selectAll(".no-attr").each(function(){
    let id= d3.select(this).attr("id");
    let data = null;
    data = props.data[0];

    for(i = 0;i < props.data.length; i++){
      if(id == prefix +props.data[i]._id){
        data = props.data[i];
        break;
      }
    }

    if( data !== null){
    d3.select(this)
      .attr(data.coordinates)
      .attr(data.style)
      .attr("class", null);
    }

  }
);
}
```

`props.data` contains all the objects with the relevant svg data.
The problem I have right now, is that sometimes when this method is invoked,
D3 starts duplicating already existing SVG elements, even though the amount of data in props.data has not changed.

Can anyoe help me with that?

Comment: objectsRender.exit().remove();

Comment: It doesn't work for me, duplicate svg elements are stil created

Comment: `svg.selectAll("line")` should probably be `svg.selectAll(".no-attr")`.  My guess is you are selecting the wrong things, but I don't know what you are actually appending...